# .class uploaded on FTP server using FTPClient is corrupted

Tags: java, ftp, ftp-client, ftp-server

I am uploading a .class file on FTP server. The uploaded file is not empty but is surely corrupted as I am not able to de-compile it. I suspect there is a different way of uploading .class files on FTP server.

Here is the snippet:

```
public boolean uploadFileOnFTPServer(File file, String uploadToPath) { 
    //file - File stored on local system that is to be uploaded on server
    //uploadToPath - Remote server path where the file is to be stored

    boolean isUploaded = false;
    try {
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
       //InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

        if (connectToFTPServer()) { // connectToFTPServer() - method to connect to server
            ftpClient.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE); // ftpClient is an object of FTPClient class

            if (ftpClient.login(userName, password)) {
                System.out.println("Logged in to server. Username: " + userName);
                if (ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(uploadToPath)) {
                    System.out.println("Navigated to path " + uploadToPath);                                                              

                    if (ftpClient.storeFile(file.getName(), inputStream)) {
                        inputStream.close();
                        System.out.println("File " + file.getName() + " uploaded to server.");
                        isUploaded = true;
                    }

                } 
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        strRemarks = "Exception reported: Unable to upload file. Error Details: " + e.toString();
        System.out.println(strRemarks);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        disconnectFTPServer();
    }
    return isUploaded;
}
```

Comment: It looks OK. Are the files the same size?

Comment: Nop. On local system, size of .class is 7013 and size of uploaded ones is 7095

Comment: That suggests that it got uploaded in text mode, and that CR/LF translation occurred. Try moving the file type setting to after the login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

**Adding setFileType() after getting connected to server but before transfer of file.**

```
                    ftpClient.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);                 
                    String remoteFileName = file.getName();
                    if (ftpClient.storeFile(remoteFileName, inputStream)) {
                        inputStream.close();
                        System.out.println("File " + file.getName() + " uploaded to server.");
                        isUploaded = true;
                    }
```

Thanks a lot EJP :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried uploading text file in binary mode to see what is actually transferred?

I also suggest specify encoding

```
client.setControlEncoding(encoding);
client.connect(host, port);
```

which should be done before connecting.